# Add a custom job factory in quartz .net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, quartz.net

Hello I have created a custom job factory as below

```
class JobFactory : IJobFactory
    {
        protected readonly IServiceProvider _container;

        public JobFactory(IServiceProvider container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            var job = (IJob)_container.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType)!;
            var logTime = _container.GetService<ILogTime>()!;
            return new JobLogDecorator(job,logTime);
        }

        public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
        {
            (job as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

The JobLogDecorator is a simple class that logs the elapsed time which decorate the job

```
public class JobLogDecorator : IJob
    {
        private readonly IJob _decorated;
        private readonly ILogTime _log;

        public JobLogDecorator (IJob decorated, ILogTime log)
        {
            _decorated = decorated;
            _log = log;
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            var jobName = context.JobDetail.Key.Name;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                await _decorated.Execute(context);

                _log.Log(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, jobName);

        }
    }
```

Now I want to register quartz and this job factory.
In startup I have registered but I cannot understand how to register my custom job factory

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
                {
                    q.SchedulerId = "MyJob";
                    q.SchedulerName = "MyJob";
                    
                    //i try to add this but i cannot hit the JobLogDecorator when the job is running
                    q.UseJobFactory<JobFactory>();
                    //i cannot understand how to configure this method
                    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

                });

                services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
                {
                    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
                });
```

As a result i cannot hit/call JobFactory ,JobLogDecorator
Also i have register `services.AddSingleton<JobFactory>();`

Comment: Did you register the factory in DI `services.AddSingleton<IJobFactory, JobFactory>()` before you've configured Quartz? https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/10e11164b5b78ea55ce66abc82e8c70ac6728224/src/Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L67-L68

Comment: @abdusco i just try also this but ia cannot call the JobLogDecorator and the jobfactory

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem when you want to register your custom Factory you have to follow these steps

1. register the factory `q.UseJobFactory<JobFactory>();`
2. Remove `q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();`
3. register the job and not the factory for example if I have MaintenanceJob i register this job as `services.AddTransient<MaintenanceJob>();`

Comment: Can you update your answer with more complete examples? You'll earn an upvote from me if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rigth way to use it. Important is to install Quartz Quartz.Extensions.DependencyInjection and Quartz.Extensions.Hosting

First is to create the Job u want to use.

```
 public class ImportJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IImportService _dataService;

    public ImportJob(IImportService dataImportService)
    {
        _dataImportService = dataImportService;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        await _dataImportService.CreateAsync();
    }
}
```

Next register the Job

```
services.AddTransient<ImportJob>();
```

Then do the Quartz Config

```
    services.AddQuartz(q =>
    {
        var jobKey = new JobKey("ImportJob");
        q.AddJob<ImportJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

        q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
            .ForJob(jobKey)
            .WithIdentity("ImportJob-trigger")
            .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(10, 48, 0)));
    });
    services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
```